# Why I get HashMap cannot be resolved to a type error?

Tags: java

Here is my Java code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


    public class Polynomial<K> {
        Map<Integer, Object> polynomial;

        public Polynomial(){
            polynomial = new HashMap<K, V>();
        }
        public  Polynomial(int numberOfMembers){
            polynomial = new HashMap<K, V>(numberOfMembers);
        }
        public void addElm(int power, int coefficient){
            if (power < 0) {
                power = Math.abs(power);
                throw new RuntimeException("ERROR: The power must be an absolute number, converting to absolute");
            }
            for (Map.Entry m : polynomial.entrySet()) {
                if ((Integer) m.getKey() == power){
                    polynomial.put(power,m.getValue());
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

On this two rows:

```
polynomial = new HashMap<K, V>();
```

and this:

```
polynomial = new HashMap<K, V>(numberOfMembers);
```

I get this error:

```
HashMap<K,V> cannot be resolved to a type
```

Any idea what cause to the error above and how to fix it?

Comment: You have `K` where did you get `V`?

Comment: `power = Math.abs(power);` is a no-op since that value is promptly ignored. Likely the runtime optimizer will remove the line altogether, heck, the compiler might even do that, so you might as well, too. There's no point in keeping code that does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you actually intend to use the generics you are have.

When you create a `new HashMap<K,V>()`, those `<K,V>` values are the actual class names for the types that the HashMap will hold. In your case, those types are Integer and Object so you should write `new HashMap<Integer, Object>()`.

Even that is unnecessary however because Java can infer the type of the HashMap since you have already defined it once. It is best to just use new `HashMap<>();`

```
public class Polynomial {

    Map<Integer, Object> polynomial;

    public Polynomial() {
        polynomial = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Polynomial(int numberOfMembers) {
        polynomial = new HashMap<>(numberOfMembers);
    }

    public void addElm(int power, int coefficient) {
        if (power < 0) {
            power = Math.abs(power);
            throw new RuntimeException("ERROR: The power must be an absolute number, converting to absolute");
        }
        for (Entry<Integer, Object> m : polynomial.entrySet()) {
            if ((Integer) m.getKey() == power) {
                polynomial.put(power, m.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You write `Map<Integer, Object> polynomial;`. This means `polynomial` is a `Map` that needs `Integer` and `Object` but then you assign `polynomial = new HashMap<K, V>();`. The class `K` and `V` are not `Integer` and `Object` thus the error.

You could write

```
polynomial = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
```

then it would work. What are the types you actually want? Why did you even wrote `K, V` in the first place? Or else, why the `Integer, Object`, why not stick to `K` and `V`? And also, if you would like to hold `V` generic you need to add it to `class Polynomial<K, V>` too.